# Change number of breaks in colorbar heatmap Julia

Tags: plot, julia, heatmap, plots.jl

I am trying to change the number of breaks in the legend of a heatmap. I am using the example from [docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/stable/generated/unitfulrecipes_plots/) to make it reproducible:

```
using Unitful, Plots

xs = [string("x", i) for i = 1:10]
ys = [string("y", i) for i = 1:4]
z = float((1:4) * reshape(1:10, 1, :)) * u"km"
heatmap(xs, ys, z, aspect_ratio=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Imagine I want for example only 4 breaks so: 5, 15, 25, 35. How can we change the number of breaks in a heatmap in `Julia`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colorbar_ticks` but they are not supported by `gr()` so you will need to switch to `pyplot()` backend:

```
pyplot()
heatmap(xs, ys, z, aspect_ratio=1, colorbar_ticks=[5, 15, 25, 35] .* u"km")
```

[image]